# Sinch Conference Call in Android Studio

Tags: sinch

Does anybody know how to invite a user to conference room and invited user can check whether if conference room is going on or has already ended? Also how invited user can see how many user are connected and disconnected to and form that conference room?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.sinch.com/docs/voice-rest-api-calling-api#section-get-conference-info

That enpoint will return participants, that enpoints will also return 404 if its not created.

Comment: but i am getting problem in bearer token. How i can test it in postman. I am getting unauthorized token. Can you help me in this ??

Comment: https://callingapi.sinch.com/v1/conferences/id/myConference header: x-timestamp:2020-02-05T09:40:08Z content-type:application/json and bearer token i have passed is App secret